# Convert named vector to dataframe

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I have this named vector:

```
x <-  1:5

names(x) <- c('0 15', '1 15', '2 15', '0 16', '1 16')
```

What is the best way to convert `x` to this dataframe:

```
xDF <- data.frame(V1 = c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1), V2 = c(15, 15, 15, 16, 16), V3 = 1:5)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a very direct approach:

```
cbind(read.table(text = names(x)), x)
     V1 V2 x
0 15  0 15 1
1 15  1 15 2
2 15  2 15 3
0 16  0 16 4
1 16  1 16 5
```

In this case, `read.table` will automatically take care of splitting your `names(x)` component (by default, by space, but other characters could be specified if necessary).

You can also set the name for `x` directly in `cbind`:

```
cbind(read.table(text = names(x)), V3 = x)
```

---

A more direct approach would be to use `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package, like this:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(stack(x), "ind", " ")
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd do something like this:

```
res = data.frame(cbind(do.call('rbind', strsplit(names(x), " ")), x))
res
     V1 V2 x
0 15  0 15 1
1 15  1 15 2
2 15  2 15 3
0 16  0 16 4
1 16  1 16 5
```

Do mind that the data types are not correct yet, the first two columns are `factor`'s.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution using `enframe` and then `separate`

```
library(tidyverse)
enframe(x, name = "v12", value = "v3") %>% 
  separate(v12, into = c("v1", "v2"))
```