# Convert named vector to df with bind_rows

Tags: r

I have a named vector:

```
dput(model_object$regression_feature_importance_matrix)
c(spend_7d = 0.704766041126329, d7_utility_sum = 0.168417670114147, 
recent_utility_ratio = 0.101030461314979, IOS = 0.0096061893294683, 
is_publisher_organic = 0.008247148545793, is_publisher_facebook = 0.0079324895692841
```

Looks like this:

```
model_object$regression_feature_importance_matrix
             spend_7d        d7_utility_sum  recent_utility_ratio                   IOS  is_publisher_organic is_publisher_facebook 
          0.704766041           0.168417670           0.101030461           0.009606189           0.008247149           0.007932490
```

I'd like to transpose it and make into a data frame. I can do this with:

```
    model_object$regression_feature_importance_matrix %>% bind_rows() %>% t() %>% data.frame() %>% rownames_to_column() %>% rename(Feature = rowname)
                Feature           .
1              spend_7d 0.704766041
2        d7_utility_sum 0.168417670
3  recent_utility_ratio 0.101030461
4                   IOS 0.009606189
5  is_publisher_organic 0.008247149
6 is_publisher_facebook 0.007932490
```

1) Is there a more elegant, shorter way of doing this? `model_object$regression_feature_importance_matrix %>% bind_rows() %>% t() %>% data.frame() %>% rownames_to_column()`

I just imagined that presumably converting a named vector to a df is rally common and I wondered if there was an out of box way?

2) I tried to rename:

Works fine:    `model_object$regression_feature_importance_matrix %>% bind_rows() %>% t() %>% data.frame() %>% rownames_to_column() %>% rename(Feature = rowname)`

Does not work:

```
model_object$regression_feature_importance_matrix %>% bind_rows() %>% t() %>% data.frame() %>% rownames_to_column() %>% rename(Feature = rowname, Gain = .)
Error in rename(Feature = rowname, Gain = .) : object 'rowname' not found
```

I think I know why. The dot represents the previous object passed in the pipe operator whereas I want to reference the column name so that I can change it. How can I change the column name '.' to 'Gain' within the same dplyr pipe? As opposed to just `names(df) <- c('Features', 'Gain')`

Comment: `tibble::enframe` does this. You can also call `rename` with column positions rather than names

Comment: enframe() - perfect!

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020476/convert-named-vector-to-dataframe) answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also use `stack` to convert named vector to dataframe and then use `rename_all`

```
stack(x)[2:1] %>% dplyr::rename_all(~c("Feature","Gain"))

#                Feature        Gain
#1              spend_7d 0.704766041
#2        d7_utility_sum 0.168417670
#3  recent_utility_ratio 0.101030461
#4                   IOS 0.009606189
#5  is_publisher_organic 0.008247149
#6 is_publisher_facebook 0.007932490
```

**data**

```
x <- c(spend_7d = 0.704766041126329, d7_utility_sum = 0.168417670114147, 
recent_utility_ratio = 0.101030461314979, IOS = 0.0096061893294683, 
is_publisher_organic = 0.008247148545793, is_publisher_facebook = 0.0079324895692841)
```